# EF Core - how to select count from child table based on foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

`TableB` has a field `TableAId` which is linked to the `Id` of `TableA`. I want to select the count from `TableB` based on `TableAId` like -

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB where tableB.TableAId = tableA.Id) as count
FROM tableA
```

So far I have the code:

```
var data = _context.TableA.AsQueryable();
...
data = data.Select(l => l.TableAId= p.Id).Count();
```

But on the last line, p is not recognized as a variable.

How do I make this work?

**EDIT :**

my original query is quiet complex and already filtering data

```
var data = _context.TableA.AsQueryable();
data = data.Include(p => p.SomeClassA)
           .Include(p => p.SomeClassB);
data = data.Where(p => p.Id == somevalue);
data = data.Where(p => p.SomeClassA.Name.Contains(someothervalue));
data = data.Where(p => p.SomeClassA.SomeField.Contains(yetanothervalue));
```

I tried adding this but it cannot compile
(TableAId & Count do not exist):

```
data = data.Join(
    _context.TableB,
    groupByQuery => groupByQuery.TableAId ,
    TableA => TableA.Id,
    (groupByQuery, TableAItem) => new
    {
        TableAId = groupByQuery.Id,
        Count = groupByQuery.Count,
        TableAItem = TableAItem
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi @phil123456, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in count, then do the following:

```
    var data = _context.TableB.AsQueryable();
    var groupByCountQuery = data.GroupBy(a=>a.TableAId, (tableAId, tableBItems) => new 
    {
        TableAId = tableAId,
        Count = tableBItems.Count()
    });
    
    var result = groupByCountQuery.ToList(); // or change to ToListAsync()
```

This will give you the count based on TableAId.

If you need the tableA items as well in the result, following ca be done:

```
        var groupByCountQuery = data.GroupBy(a=>a.TableAId, (tableAId, tableBItems) => new 
        {
            TableAId = tableAId,
            Count = tableBItems.Count()
        }).Join(_context.TableA, 
                groupByQuery => groupByQuery.TableAId, 
                tableA => tableA.Id,
               (groupByQuery , tableA) => new {
                   TableAId = groupByQuery.TableAId,
                   Count = groupByQuery.Count,
                   TableAItem = tableA
                } );
```

Comment: it also means I would have to parse the returned list to merge it with the previous query... is there no way to use one single query ? especially since my main query is filtering

Comment: I modified the question (see bottom)

Comment: You are missing the parentheses in Count = groupByQuery.Count(). Count is a method, not a property. Also, can you give a little more detail on how are you constructing groupByQuery?

Comment: ok but groupByQuery comes from your code, I dont construct it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start from TableA, you can use the following linq query:

```
var data = _context.TableAs.AsQueryable();

        var x = (from a in data
                 join b in _context.TableBs on a.Id equals b.TableAId
                 group a.TableB by a.Id into g
                 select new
                 {
                     TableAId = g.Key,
                     TableBItem = g.FirstOrDefault(),
                     Count = g.Count()
                 }).ToList();
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `TableA` has properties - Id, FieldA1 and FieldA2.

First, you have to include `TableB` in your query so that you can take its count, like -

```cs
var data = _context.TableA.Include(p=> p.TableB).AsQueryable();
```

Then in the `Select` method you have to create a new object with `TableA`'s properties and `TableB`'s count, like -

```cs
var list = data.Select(p =>
new
{
    Id = p.Id,
    A1 = p.FieldA1,
    A2 = p.FieldA2,
    Count = p.OrderLines.Count
}).ToList();
```

Notice, this is assigned to a new variable `list`. That is because it does not return a list of `TableA`, it returns a list of an anonymous object with properties - Id, A1, A2 and Count. Therefore, you cannot assign it to the previously declared `data` variable, because `data` is of type `IQueryable<TableA>`.

Alternatively, you can declare a class to hold the data values, like -

```cs
public class MyData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string A1 { get; set; }
    public string A2 { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

and use it like -

```cs
var list = data.Select(p =>
new MyData
{
    Id = p.Id,
    A1 = p.FieldA1,
    A2 = p.FieldA2,
    Count = p.OrderLines.Count
}).ToList();
```